# Motion in insulating fluid under high voltage

Tags: electricity, home-experiment

I observed the following phenomenon in an experiment (I'm not a student of physics, just an amateur) and was hoping for an explanation.

[image]

A metal pan is electrically grounded and a layer of insulating fluid (vegetable oil) is placed in the pan.  If you like, assume the pan is infinite in diameter.  An electrode (a needle) is placed above the pan, pointing downward at the oil.  A high voltage (-12kV) is applied to the electrode.  The electrode is close enough to the pan to generate an ion wind, but not close enough to overcome the breakdown voltage of the air and oil, so there is no arc.  The oil is repelled from the electrode (perhaps because it acquires a negative charge from the ion wind) and also, more remarkably, the surface of the oil begins to undulate.

My theory to explain the undulation is that the negatively charged oil on the surface is repelled from the electrode until it touches the pan, where it loses its charge and therefore is permitted to rise to the surface again, and the process repeats.  So the undulations are something like convection cells, only with electric charge instead of heat.

Is this explanation correct?  Is there a name for this phenomenon?  Would a similar phenomenon create leakage current in capacitors with liquid dielectrics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial explanation is close to what happens in reality. Let us call things by their names; the discharge you initiate by biasing the needle is called a [Corona discharge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge) (if the pressure was much lower it becomes a [glow discharge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glow_discharge)). The configuration you built is called a [dielectric barrier discharge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_barrier_discharge), for short a DBD.

In a corona discharge streamers form to connect the anode to the cathode. The streamer is basically a channel of partially ionized gas that is capable of carrying current between the electrodes. The streamer starts to from by local ionization of gas molecules in the vicinity of the needle. So a plasma cloud forms there, at the other edge of the plasma cloud (the edge away from the needle) a strong electric field is generated which accelerates the local electrons there giving them the necessary energy to ionize gas molecules. The energetic electrons create a plasma cloud there (which is connected to the plasma cloud next to the needle from one side), the process continues until the streamer connects the needle to oil surface. This phenomenon of generating streamer is called ionization wave propagation.

When the streamer edge arrives at oil surface, negatively charged particles (electrons and negative O2 ions) are deposited on the surface, creating a local negatively charged spot. At this particular spot the pressure of oil increases, which from Navier-Stokes equations cause the fluid to move in the direction of decreasing pressure.

This particular phenomenon has been studied experimentally in the late 90s. The motion of oil is called Electrohydrodynamic surface waves (EHD). Have a look at [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304388601001140) where they study a very similar configuration to yours.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at that paper.  I don't think that what you said about streamers describes my setup. There were no streamers between the point electrode and the oil surface, and there was no plasma cloud around the oil surface.  The formation of ions was confined to a small stable region around the point electrode, as in http://pac.iupac.org/publications/pac/pdf/1985/pdf/5709x1353.pdf, p.2, but with the polarities reversed.  Does this affect your answer?

Comment: Plasma in the general sense is a mixture of ions and electrons, it doesn't necessarily need to be glowing at an intensity you can observe with your naked eyes. Researchers working in the atmospheric pressure range use special cameras to observe the glow of the plasma at that pressure. The glow is observed at the tip of the streamer moving at timescale of nanoseconds. I don't know what makes you think it is not the streamer scenario, can you tell? The difference in polarity is not a big deal. Instead of ions moving toward the oil electrons move.

Comment: To be precise, changing the polarit makes some differences in the mechanisms of ionization and transport of charged species. But in the general layout it is not different

Comment: Okay, perhaps all the air in the vicinity of the experiment satisfies the definition of "plasma" in some weak sense because it contains ions. However, I think ions are only being _formed_ near the point electrode.  The reason I say there were no streamers is that I know what streamers look like and I didn't see them.  It appeared to be a unipolar corona.  (Surely you acknowledge the existence of such a thing?)

Comment: Also, I didn't say that the difference in polarity was a big deal, but actually negative and positive coronas do behave differently as explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge#Negative_coronas and also in my earlier link.

Comment: I think both of us is partially correct. If you read page 2 of your earlier link you will see that you are talking about unipolar case while I am talking about the bipolar case (called streamer in the link). Being unipolar or bipolar doesn't necessarily depend on the polarity of the electrodes. I can't be certain whether your experimental setup it unipolar or bipolar. So it might be one or a combination of the two cases. Streamers are in general broader than the bright filaments we know, as I mentioned earlier they don't necessarily be bright enough to be observed by naked eyes

Comment: Lastly, with respect to polarity it makes a qualitative difference not a quantitative one, I mean regardless of the polarity the discharge has the same nature, it doesn't become an arc discharge if you changed the polarity for example. The difference stays within the borders of Corona discharge

Comment: Yes, I know that it is possible for a unipolar corona to form around the point electrode regardless of its polarity relative to the plate electrode.  I only mentioned that it was negative so that you'd have all the information. Regarding unipolar vs. bipolar, let's just _assume_ that the corona is unipolar, since there seems to be no way that I can convince you of this.  In this case we get an ion wind depositing negative charge smoothly across the surface of the oil, rather than concentrated in spots like we would get if there were streamers.  Would this change your answer?

Comment: Also, not that it matters to the question as far as I can tell, but from what I have heard and seen a corona discharge between a point electrode and a plate electrode could become an arc if the polarity is reversed.  That is, the breakdown voltage in this electrode configuration does indeed depend on the polarity.

Comment: When you posted this question I suppose you didn't know where to look. Now that you know, you are a much better judge than me because you see the experiment while the only thing I have is a brief description. I thought of streamers because the description of EHD states that oil surface waves start from a localized point on the surface, so streamers came to my mind. Speaking of the polarity I didn't know it could change the discharge, I will do some reading on it. It is unfortunate that I can't give you a definite answer but I hope I helped you to get one

Comment: Thanks again for the reference.  I am still reading it and trying to figure out whether it describes the same phenomenon (one possible difference is that they use a solid dielectric layer between the ground plate and the oil; I'll try doing it this way myself when I get the chance.)

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but a follow up query.  I would love to use an experiment similar to this in my chemistry class.  The electric charge build up would cause an induced dipole within the oil molecules.  This momentary charge separation would cause other oil molecules to be repelled.  In fact, it seems holding a strongly negatively charged source near a bowl of oil should cause a standing wave pattern.

Can anyone post the necessary equipment to perform this experiment?  Voltage source, type of oil etc would be helpful.  I think a demonstration like this would be of great value to my students and I thank any respondents on behalf of them.

Comment: I used a neon sign transformer with its output rectified by a high voltage diode (which I think was really a stack of silicon diodes in an insulated package; I forget where I obtained it.)  Minimal current is required, so any DC voltage source in the vicinity of 12 kV should work.  Less might be okay, but I'd guess you probably need 5 kV at the very least.  For safety, use a current-limited source (*not* a microwave oven transformer.)  For the electrode, I used a sewing needle.  I don't know if it needs to be that sharp.  I think I used canola oil.  It might be worth trying mineral oil also.

Comment: It was an old neon sign transformer that looked like this one: http://www.theneonsignguystore.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/12000-v-neon-transformer-e1363615745333.jpg  I'm not sure if the newer, smaller ones will work.

Comment: It might be worth trying a voltage multiplier from an air ionizer.  Those are probably cheaper than neon sign transformers.

Comment: 12 kV sounds like a bucketload of voltage.  Since my DC current comes from AA batteries, where would I get such a high voltage source to run a neon light transformer, let alone find a high voltage diode.  As a chemist I do not worry about dealing with chemicals but handling 12 kV sounds daunting.  Can you allay my concerns?

Comment: For safety and ease of use, the best thing would probably be a power supply module for an air ionizer (negative ion generator).  You can search for "12V high density negative ion generator" on amazon, for example.  They are little black boxes that you can connect to 12V DC (e.g. from batteries) and produce a high output voltage at what I assume is a safe power level.